# Java : Best way to dynamically create method calling sequence

Tags: java, jbehave

I have started working on a BDD project using JBehave. I need to build a sequence of methods to be called based on the steps "Given", "When" and finally execute them in "Then". A sample would be like

Given a user logins as a premium user
When he adds an item to the cart
Then he gets a special discount

For the above scenario, I would have to build method call sequence based on "Given" / "When" and then execute the same in "Then"

E.g.

```
List<Executable> sequenceList
@Given
public void execGiven()
{

  A a = new A();
  a.call1()
  a.call2()
  B b = new B();
  b.call3();

}

@When
public void execWhen(){
C c = new C();
c.call4();
//...few more methods

@Then
public void execThen(){
//Add some methods to the list of executables
D d = new D();
d.call5();
Assert if everything successful
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the framework we are using(in built and in use) cannot be used to partially execute the method call sequences in each Step of a story. Rather, I have to execute them as a whole sequence( from a.call1 to d.call5).Also another issue is that I dont want to hardcode the method calls for each step instead call them based on some config at runtime.

My Approach.
Instead of running these methods (a.call1 , a.call2) in each step, add them to a list of Methods and execute them in "Then" using reflections. Also use annotations like

```
@Sequence(step="Login" , sequenceId=1) for each method so that at runtime I can build a list of calls to be made.
```

What would be a good approach considering that any change in the method call sequence is less painful to change. I had few approaches in mind

Use annotations to wire the sequence
Use xml to wire the sequence
Use a text file to mention the sequence(almost same as above)

Is there any better approach to build the graph in the runtime and execute the sequence? Also any drawbacks of the same?

Thank You

Comment: Can you give more deatils on how such a story would look like, why excatly you need to use given and when in then and what you want to archive by that? Right now, your question is quite vargue...

Comment: Very simple example would look like:
Given a premium user logins to the server
When he adds an item to the cart
Then check if he is given some special discount

Now I need to build a sequence which I want to execute in the "Then" based on the parameters submitted in "Given" and "When". We need this to adapt JBehave to our already existing framework which we are using for our test execution. I will edit the main question as well.